# Why am I unable to use some Python modules? Numpy, Scipy and others just print numbers to inf when imported. How can I stop this?

Tags: windows, windows-10, python, python3

Whenever I import them they just go crazy printing numbers out (Always the same numbers, I think). It's at the point of import, so running the `import numpy` in the shell makes it happen straight away (as shown in this image):

[image]

It does it both in IDLE and in CMD.

I've tried reinstalling, installing previous versions, and other install methods (installing from the website instead of pip), and trying in different versions of Python, what could be wrong? Everything works fine on my Linux raspberry pi obviously. I'm on Windows by the way, but you knew that when I said CMD; Windows 10.

No one else mentions the problem online that I have seen so far.

Comment: How are you using them? If you're the only person having these problems the first question to ask yourself is whether or not you're using them correctly, and the first bit of information you'll have to give anyone you hope could help you solve your problem is exactly how you are using them.

Comment: Like I said, and illustrated, the problem occurs when I run the line 'import numpy', am I using it wrong?